# @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) doesn't initialize mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using Junit 4.8.2. When I run my test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and just annotate mocks with @Mock, it doesn't seem to initialize the mocks. But when I use the static mock() and get rid of the runner and annotations, I can see that the mocks are initialized.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass
{
    private static final String DOMAIN = "mock";

    @Mock private TransactionManager transactionManager;
    @Mock private SearchManager searchManager;

    private final filter = new Filter(transactionManager,searchManager, DOMAIN);

    @Test
    public void myTest()
    {
        filter.callMethod();      // This throws NPE since transactionManager was null
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have looked into this [Initialising mock objects - MockIto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494926/initialising-mock-objects-mockito]) and have done everything according to it but still no luck.

Comment: This post should have the answer to your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494926/initialising-mock-objects-mockito

Comment: @RC. You were right. If you want you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runner handles the `@Mock` annotation **after** the class is instantiated, so move the `filter = new Filter(transactionManager,searchManager, DOMAIN);` in a `@Before` annotated method:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass
{
    private static final String DOMAIN = "mock";

    @Mock 
    private TransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Mock 
    private SearchManager searchManager;

    private Filter filter;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        filter = new Filter(transactionManager, searchManager, DOMAIN);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        filter.callMethod(); // No more NPE
    }
}
```

From the [runner doc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html):

> Initializes mocks annotated with `@Mock`, so that explicit usage of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Object)` is not necessary. **Mocks are initialized before each test method.**

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing your mocks, adding a setup method to your test class.

You will also probably need to move your `filter` initialization inside it:

```
private filter;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    filter = new Filter(transactionManager,searchManager, DOMAIN);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did have to move the filter object. But we don't need MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); if we use the runner

Comment: But you need them initialized before initializing the filter, so that's how.

Comment: I'd guess that you can move the filter to inside your test and remove the initMocks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@InjectMock` over your test object. If you use `@InjectMock` , it will use mocked object to create your test object.