# JUnit running test methods conditionally

Tags: java, junit, junit4

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
public class SwiftTest {
    SwiftUtil swiftUtil = new SwiftUtil();
    boolean result;
    @Test
    public void checkInPathFolder()
    {
        result = swiftUtil.checkInPathFolder();
        assertTrue(result);
    }
    @Test
    public void checkCustomObjectExists()
    {
        result=swiftUtil.validateWFId();
        assertTrue(result);
    }
    @Test
    public void runSwift()
    {
        result=swiftUtil.runSwiftBatch();
        assertTrue(result);
    }
    @Test
    public void checkTreatedFolder()
    {
        result=swiftUtil.checkTreatedFolder();
        assertTrue(result);
    }
    @Test
    public void checkExceptionFolder()
    {
        result=swiftUtil.checkExceptionFolder();
        assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

Above is my Test case. based on two cases i want to execute set of above test methods.

For eg:

1. On Condition X, only `checkInPathFolder()`, `checkCustomObjectExists()`, `runSwift()` should be executed.
2. On Condition Y, `checkInPathFolder()`, `runSwift()`, `checkExceptionFolder()` should be executed.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Why not just put the condidition in the method body?

Comment: Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489388/how-junit-rule-works).

Comment: suppose for a condition X all above test cases execute which is not desirable(as undesirable test cases fail). for for X i want only 3 test cases to be executed(all will be successful). if i put some condition (eg: Assume true) in method body even undesired cases execute as success.

Comment: Does it really matter if a test that should not have been run, runs with success?

Comment: yeah, thts the main issse. if it was not a matter of concern,
Assert.assertTrue(false) works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JUnit's `assume` mechanism described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4). You will need to use either `Theories` of `Parameterized` to cause `JUnit` to execute more than once if you want to drive those two conditions.