# How to share an ExternalResource between two test classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit-rule

I am struggling a bit to understand the benefit of using `ExternalResource`.  The [documentation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) and other posts ([How Junit @Rule works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489388/how-junit-rule-works/13489506#13489506)) have all alluded to being able to share code between tests within a class and/or share code between test classes.

I am trying to use `ExternalResource` for a DB connection in a functional/integration test, but I don't see how I can share that connection across classes. In fact, I don't really see the benefit over `@Before/@After` in this case.  Am I using this incorrectly or what am I missing?

```
public class some_IntegrationTest {

    private static String id;
    Connection connection = null;

    //...

    @Rule
    public ExternalResource DBConnectionResource = new ExternalResource() {
        @Override
        protected void before() throws SQLException {
            connection = DbUtil.openConnection();
        }

        @Override
        protected void after() {
            DbUtil.closeConnection(connection);
        }
    };

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass setUpClass");
        cleanup(id);
    }

    //I want to do something like this
    @Test
    public void test01() {
        cleanupData(connection, id);
        // do stuff...
    }

    @Test
    public void test02() {
        cleanupTnxLog(connection, id);
        // do stuff...
    }

    //...


    private static void cleanup(String id) throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.info("Cleaning up records");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DbUtil.openConnection();
            cleanupData(connection, id);
            cleanupTnxLog(connection, id);
        } finally {
            DbUtil.closeConnection(connection);
        }
    }

    private static void cleanupData(Connection connection, String id)
        throws SQLException {
        dao1.delete(connection, id);
    }

    private static void cleanupTnxLog(Connection connection, String id)
        throws SQLException {
        dao2.delete(connection, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea behind resources is to have something self-contained (like start a webserver before() and stop it after())

Comment: @RC. I don't really want to share the `Connection` object between test classes. But I don't see how I can avoid copying the same Rule into every other class. The doc specifically states "ExternalResource is a base class for Rules (like TemporaryFolder) that set up an external resource before a test (a file, socket, server, database connection, etc.), and guarantee to tear it down afterward", so I assumed I can use it for database connections.

Comment: I don't see why you could not use a rule here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
public class DbConnectionRessource extends ExternalRessource {

    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void before() throws SQLException {
        connection = DbUtil.openConnection();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        DbUtil.closeConnection(connection);
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

then use it in your test like this:

```
public class SomeIntegrationTest {
    @Rule
    public DbConnectionRessource dbConnectionResource = new DbConnectionRessource();

    // ...

    @Test
    public void test01() {
        cleanupData(dbConnectionResource.getConnection(), id);
        // do stuff...
    }

    // ...
}
```

[not tested]

Comment: I tried do this earlier within the `ExternalResource` rule created within the test (which now I see of course wouldn't work because I wasn't extending... pfft)