# How do I use @RunWith with both JUnit4ClassRunner and JUnitParams?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, parameterized, springjunit4classrunner

I am writing an integration test that is a parameterized test, and I need to include @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class). The problem is that I can only specify one @RunWith. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: You're looking for junit `@Rule`s. See this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489388/how-junit-rule-works

Comment: Decide:  is it a Spring test or a Params test that you want to create?