# Creating a configurable JUnit library to test same features across several microservices

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit5, spring-test

A set of tests should be run on every microservice. Current solution is to have an `abstract class` and extend in every service, providing the necessary properties in abstract getters.

```java
public abstract class AbstractTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    protected int serverPort;

    protected abstract String getPath();
 
    @Test
    void someTest() {}

    @Test
    void conditionalTest() {}
}

@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
    classes = {...})
@ActiveProfiles(...) // etc
public class MyTest extends AbstractTest {
// ... implement getPath()
// tests from parent will be executed
}
```

**The goal:**
Ditch inheritance and have the `AbstractTest`'s logic get executed automatically with conditional `@Test` execution based on beans/properties etc.

**The possible solution:**
A concrete class with all the tests or some sort of `Configuration/TestFactory` to create the necessary tests. It should take into account available properties and beans to determine which tests to run.

**The problem:**
How can those tests (created in runtime) be discovered and registered for execution?
How to inject all the properties that are part of the current context of the `@SpringBootTest`?

**Failed attempts:**

- `TestInstanceFactory` extension doesn't seem to be the solution as it requires an instance of the class which it annotates.
- Using the Launcher API seems overkill, and also doesn't seem to work, since the library class won't be created with the Spring context configs.
- using cglib and a base class `Spring Contract`-style is not a desirable solution

Ideally I don't want the client of this lib to implement/create anything, so `abstract String getPath();` would be a `test.lib.path` property, and if it's present, a test from the library which uses it will run.

Any thoughts on this would be great, because right now this just seems impossible to me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason to have the inheritance for tests?
In case you need to share some common logic within the tests you may try JUnit features (custom rules/extensions), for example

1. For `junit < 5.x.x` @Rule functionality https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html https://stackoverflow.com/a/34608174/6916890
2. For `junit >= 5.x.x` (jupiter) there is an extension API
   https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-built-in-extensions-TempDirectory

Comment: Technically, yes, I wan't to share some common logic, but those tests are basically one liners for health/sanity checks, swagger links etc. The point is to avoid repetition, so shared code can't be in a util class. Extensions provide functionality "around" the test, so to speak, I'm looking for a way to have the actual tests running.